# GAE: Best way to keep track of number of entities of an NDB kind?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to keeping track of the number of entities of a certain NDB kind I have in my cloud datastore.

One approach is just, when I want to know how many I have, get the `.count()` of a query that I know will return all of them, but that costs a ton of datastore small operations (looks like it's proportional to the number of entities of that kind I have). So that's not ideal.

Another option would be having a counter in the datastore that gets updated every time I create or delete an entity, but that's also not ideal because it would add an extra read and write operation to every entity I create or destroy.

As of now, it looks like the second option is my best choice, so my question is--do you agree? Are there any other options that would be more cost-effective?

Thanks a lot.

PS: Working in Python if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why do you need the count? [The docs say](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_count) count is more efficient that fetching and counting, so it looks like they might have built this to be quick for this reason already.

Comment: (if you enable billing, small datastore ops are free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a better/cheaper/faster way to see the info you are looking for but it might not work if you need to know EXACT number of fields at any given moment since its only updated couple of times a day (i.e. you can access it anytime but it may be a few hours outdated).

The "Datastore Statistics" page in GAE dashboard displays some detailed data about kinds/entities including "count" numbers and there's a way to access it programmatically. See more info here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats

Answer (score 1):

Second option is the way to go.

Other considerations:

- If you have many writes per second you may wish to consider using a [shared counter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters)
- To reduce datastore writes, you could use a cron job to update the datastore at timed intervals (ie count how many entities have been created since last run)
- Also consider using [memcache.incr()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_incr) in conjunction with a cron job to persist the data. Downside of this is you're memcache key could drop, so only really an option if the count doesn't have to be accurate.